# Remove space between image and div

Tags: css, image, html, margin, padding

I've tried **display: block;** and **vertical-align: bottom;**

Neither will remove the space between the image and the div.

I'm using HTML5 and an external CSS stylesheet.

**HTML:**

```
    <p id="missionMembers">
        <img src="" border"0"/>
    </p>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="twitter-hover social-slide"> </div>
        <div class="facebook-hover social-slide"> </div>
        <a href= "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQUQ1EHTu705qdNWaFAz0SA"/> <div class="youtube-hover social-slide"> </div></a>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#missionMembers {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
}

#footer {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    background-color:black; 
    height: 68px;
    width: 2000px;
    border: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

(#missionMembers is the image. #footer is the div.)

Comment: You have to show some code bro.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: For reference, best practice is to use `0` Instead of using `0em 0em 0em 0em` for margin, border, padding when setting to nothing.

Comment: Because zero is fundamentally unit-less.

Comment: @Jonathan I changed the `0em 0em 0em 0em` to `0` but there is still a space

Comment: a fiddle for the interested: http://jsfiddle.net/uu9nt/

Comment: @Mark As I understand, those just move the content of the div. The problem is that there is a space underneath the `#missionMembers` image separating it from the `#footer` div. I need them to be flush

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution:

```
#missionMembers {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#missionMembers img {
 display: block;
}

#footer {
 padding: 0 2em;
 margin: 0;
 background-color:black; 
 height: 68px;
 width: 2000px;
 border: 0;
}
```

Comment: I still see the space, but now the image is no longer centered

Comment: Include `margin:0 auto;` to `#missionMembers img {` and the image will be centred.

Comment: However, I'm still facing the issue of the space

Comment: @Jonathan I see that it works in JSFiddle, but when I just copied and pasted that into my code and previewed in Google Chrome, the space was still there.

Comment: @Jonathan could it have anything to do with the fact that I changed the width of the footer to `2000px` The only reason I had it set to that was because I didn't know how to properly create a div that would fit to the browser window, so I created one that went longer than it (`2000px') and set the `overflow-x` to hidden in the `body {`. Is there a better solution to that so that it won't mess up the `#footer` div if in fact it is doing so?

Comment: @user3198962 would setting the footers width to `100%` not be better at that would span the screen? I have just tried the footer with `2000px` width and it still works within the fiddle. Could you have some other CSS or mark-up effecting it?

Comment: @Jonathan I set the width of the footer to `100%`, but I'm still seeing the space. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lopesdsgn/kjmtL/) for the entire code

Comment: @user3198962 the margins are collapsing between the two `P` elements, if you can add `p{margin:0;}` to your CSS to solve this.